# Anchor tags in PDF are not clickable in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, safari, anchor

I have an iframe which loads PDF. It loads PDF successfully in all browsers. But anchor tags inside those PDFs are not clickable in Firefox and safari.
In works fine in google chrome. 
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: http://www.realtimecases.com/system/cases_offereds/media/000/000/009/original/Public_Relations_Communications_Overview.pdf?1453309175

This PDF contains a link at left bottom. But it is not clickable in safari and firefox

Comment: Yes.. its clickable in chrome. But not possible in safari and firefox

Comment: It works in Safari for me, not in Firefox though.

Comment: When I change my settings like they say on the website linked below the hyperlinks work. https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/1042490

Comment: @Purple I don't think you're talking about the same issue. The poster is talking about opening the link within the PDF, not opening the PDF within a plugin.

Comment: HI all,
in safari the link will redirect, but not showing any hyperlink symbol when mouse-overing it.
while in firefox nothing will happen

Comment: yes, it's not working with default PDF viewer in firefox but when we change the viewer to adobe reader 9.1 it is showing link. Is there any custom viewer js which will work like chrome viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks working when used Embeddable Google Document Viewer (http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html).

```
Working:
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.realtimecases.com/system/cases_offereds/media/000/000/009/original/Public_Relations_Communications_Overview.pdf?1453309175&embedded=true" width="100%" height="900"></iframe>
```